# Checking if NIC controller has SR-iov capability

Tags: networking, virtualization, nic, broadcom, sr-iov

I'm trying to use SR-IOV with openstack, and in order to check if the NIC available on my servers support this technolony I did the following:

```
(venv) [root@controller share]#  lshw -c network -businfo
Bus info          Device      Class          Description
========================================================
pci@0000:02:00.0  eno3        network        NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
pci@0000:02:00.1  eno4        network        NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
pci@0000:01:00.0  eno1        network        NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
pci@0000:01:00.1  eno2        network        NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
pci@0000:05:00.0              network        MT27500 Family [ConnectX-3]
```

and then :

```
(venv) [root@controller share]# lspci -vs 0000:02:00.0
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
    DeviceName: NIC3
    Subsystem: Dell Device 1f5b
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51, NUMA node 0
    Memory at d58a0000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Memory at d58b0000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Memory at d58c0000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Expansion ROM at d8000000 [disabled] [size=256K]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] Vital Product Data
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=17 Masked-
    Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number 00-00-c8-1f-66-e0-30-22
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
```

According to Redhat documentation sr-iov capable devices should have the following output with `lspci -vs` command :

> ```
>     Capabilities: [160 v1] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)
> ```

But in my case I have :

```
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
```

and after searching about this result, I couldn't find any link between **virtual channel** and **SR-IOV** , does that mean the NIC on my servers do not support Single Root I/O Virtualization ?

Answer (score 0):

yes it seems this adapter does not support SR-IOV for "Linux KVM".

[product description](https://www.broadcom.com/products/ethernet-connectivity/network-adapters/bcm5720-2p) tells only from VMware and Windows Hypervisor.

you can go with brute-force method. By suppressing host drivers to capture the card and instead assign directly to VM using this process: [dedicated NIC to VM](https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/How_to_assign_devices_with_VT-d_in_KVM)

Looking at another fiber card in the system. The output does show SR-IOV as a capability.